# ExactTarget Editor - AMPscript / SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

**Situation**

In ExactTarget (Marketing Cloud) it is possible to write AMPscript and SSJS. The only way I found for debugging AMP or SSJS is to create a public cloud page or to use email preview.

**Question**

Is there any other way to write AMPscript and SSJS for ExactTarget? Is it possible to upload "script" using an Editor like SublimeText?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If you have a publicly accessible web server you can do something like this in your email or landing page.  It's typically how our team iterates when we're building solutions:

```
%%=TreatAsContent(HttpGet(Concat("http://example.com/ampscripttest.html?x=",GUID())))=%%
```

Just create an email or landing page, add this script, then edit and push your changes to the web server.  Click next on the Send Preview or refresh your landing page to see the results.

Once everything is tested, replace your `HttpGet()` script with the actual source.

Comment: Thank you adam. Does it work for SSJS as well? And do you recommend to use a cloud page or a email template?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Landing pages have less restrictions for certain functions and are more flexible.  Depends on what you're coding.  I the `httpget()` in both places frequently.